# Integrate HornetQ(2.2.x) with Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms, hornetq

I have been going couple of docs and posts in the net for few days but couldn't manage configure it right.

I am working on Standalone environment and I am trying to integrate simply HornetQ on my Spring3.1 application.

I know I have to modify also couple of Hornetq specific xml's.

it's seems always something missing in my puzzle.

Any full simple working sample?

thanks alot,
ray.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/06/spring-3-hornetq-21-integration.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

Are you using HornetQ as embedded JMS server or using it with JBoss? In both cases it will 2 different answers. Nicholas answer related to embedded case.

I suppose you are using HornetQ integrated in Jboss, because you say you working on Standalone environment, so I recommend you not integrate JMS in Spring, but using EE feature, like EJB and MDB. It easy configurable and already there. All you need is configure it properly, create MDB for consumers and @Singleton EJB for init spring configuration.

Here is working [example](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=ru&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://grigory-panov.blogspot.com/2012/07/jboss-7.html) ([russian original](http://grigory-panov.blogspot.com/2012/07/jboss-7.html))
**EDIT**
So, full version:

1. HornetQ configs. I put here simple version with inVm connector, but you can change it to netty later.

hornetq-configuration.xml:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq/schema/hornetq-configuration.xsd">

    <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
    <create-bindings-dir>true</create-bindings-dir>
    <create-journal-dir>true</create-journal-dir>
    <!--<create-paging-dir>true</create-paging-dir>-->

    <journal-directory>/tmp/journal</journal-directory>
    <paging-directory>/tmp/paging</paging-directory>
    <bindings-directory>/tmp/binding</bindings-directory>
    <!-- disable security -->
    <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
    <!-- Connectors -->

    <connectors>
        <connector name="in-vm">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory</factory-class>
        </connector>
    </connectors>

    <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="in-vm">
            <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
        </acceptor>
    </acceptors>

    <!-- Other config -->

    <!--<security-settings>-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash;security for example queue&ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<security-setting match="#">-->
            <!--<permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>-->
            <!--<permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>-->
            <!--<permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>-->
            <!--<permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>-->
            <!--<permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>-->
            <!--<permission type="send" roles="guest"/>-->
        <!--</security-setting>-->
    <!--</security-settings>-->
</configuration>
```

hornetq-jms.xml:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:hornetq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hornetq /schema/hornetq-jms.xsd">
    <connection-factory name="ConnectionFactory">
        <connectors>
            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
        </connectors>
        <entries>
            <entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>
        </entries>
        <consumer-window-size>0</consumer-window-size>
        <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
        <retry-interval-multiplier>1.5</retry-interval-multiplier>
        <max-retry-interval>60000</max-retry-interval>
        <reconnect-attempts>1000</reconnect-attempts>
    </connection-factory>

    <!--the queue used by the example-->
    <queue name="statusQueue">
        <entry name="queue/statusQueue"/>
    </queue>
</configuration>
```

if you enable security, you should also creates hornetq-users.xml with user and roles descriptions.

spring config:

```
<bean id="jmsServer" class="org.hornetq.jms.server.embedded.EmbeddedJMS" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop"/>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory"
          class="mypackecge.JmsConnecitonFactoryLocator"
          depends-on="jmsServer"
          factory-method="lookupConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="server" ref="jmsServer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" depends-on="jmsServer">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        </property>
        <property name="destinationResolver">
            <ref bean="jmsDestResolver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestResolver" class="mypackage.EmbeddedDestinationResolver">
        <property name="server" ref="jmsServer"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="statusQueue" class="mypackage.JmsQueueLocator"
          depends-on="jmsServer"
          factory-method="lookupQueue">
        <constructor-arg name="server" ref="jmsServer"/>
        <constructor-arg name="queueName" value="queue/statusQueue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsContainerStatus" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="statusQueue"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="statusChecker" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"/>
    </bean>
```

Next, creates classes for lookup jms sessionFacroty and queues.

Destnation resolver,used by jmsTeplate to resolve where to send message.

```
public class EmbeddedDestinationResolver implements DestinationResolver {

    private EmbeddedJMS server;

    public EmbeddedJMS getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(EmbeddedJMS server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    @Override
    public Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName, boolean pubSubDomain) throws JMSException {
        return (Destination)server.lookup(destinationName);
    }
}
```

Connection factory locator.

```
public class JmsConnecitonFactoryLocator {
    public static HornetQJMSConnectionFactory lookupConnectionFactory(EmbeddedJMS server){
        HornetQJMSConnectionFactory cf = (HornetQJMSConnectionFactory) server.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        return cf;
    }
}
```

Queue locator.

```
public class JmsQueueLocator {

    public static Queue lookupQueue(EmbeddedJMS server, String queueName){
        return (Queue) server.lookup(queueName);
    }
}
```

Message handler.

```
@Component(value = "statusChecker")
public class StatusChecker implements MessageListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusChecker.class);

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
      // handle message, call message.acknowledge()
    }
```

and jmsTemplate sample for sending messages in queue:

```
@Component
public class WorkQueue {

    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void addStatusRequestToQueue(final Transaction t) throws JMSException {

        jmsTemplate.send("queue/statusQueue", new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
                msg.setText(String.valueOf(t.getId()));
                return msg;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Actually i was using HornetQ integrated with Spring not Jboss.